# Conditional Javascript based on WP Version

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-script, wordpress-version

How would I go about creating a conditional statement in PHP to load a javascript file dependent on the active version of the WP installation?

i.e. if using Wordpress 3.8 load javascript file A, if using Wordpress 3.9 load javascript file B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the function [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo). There is a special paramater called `version` that retrieves the wordpress version from the `$wp_version` variable set in wp-includes/version.php.

So you could do something like this

```
 function register_jquery_wp_version() {
    global $wp_version;
      if ( $wp_version >= 3.8 ) {
           // register and enqueue jquery A
      }elseif( $wp_version >= 3.9 ) {
          // register and enqueue jquery B
      }
   }

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_jquery_wp_version' );
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I specify the 3rd digit in the version number if applicable or I assume the function probably just reads the first two digits..?  i.e. 3.x.x

Comment: If applicable you should use the third digit.